# R: partimat function doesn't recognize my classes

Tags: r

I am a relatively novice r user and am attempting to use the partimat() function within the klaR package to plot decision boundaries for a linear discriminant analysis but I keep encountering the same error. I have tried inputing the arguments multiple different ways according to the manual, but keep getting the following error:

Error in partimat.default(x, grouping, ...) : 
  at least two classes required

Here is an example of the input I've given:

> partimat(sources1[,c(3:19)],grouping=sources1[,2],method="lda",prec=100)

where my data table is loaded in under the name "sources1" with columns 3 through 19 containing the explanatory variables and column 2 containing the classes. I have also tried doing it by entering the formula like so:

> partimat(sources1$group~sources1$tio2+sources1$v+sources1$cr+sources1$co+sources1$ni+sources1$rb+sources1$sr+sources1$y+sources1$zr+sources1$nb+sources1$la+sources1$gd+sources1$yb+sources1$hf+sources1$ta+sources1$th+sources1$u,data=sources1)

with these being the column heading.

I have successfully run an LDA on this same data set without issue so I'm not quite sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

From the source code of the partimat.default function `getAnywhere(partimat.default)` it states

```
if (nlevels(grouping) < 2) 
    stop("at least two classes required")
```

Therefore maybe you haven't defined your grouping column as a factor variable. If you try `summary(sources1[,2])` what do you get? If it's not a factor, try

```
sources1[,2] <- as.factor(sources1[,2])
```

Or in method 2 try removing the `"sources1$"`on each of your variable names in the formula as you specify the data frame in which to look for these variable names in the `data` argument. I think you are effectively specifying the dataframe twice and it might be looking, for instance, for

```
"sources1$sources1$groups"
```

Rather than

```
"sources1$groups"
```

Without further error messages or a reproducible example (i.e. include some data in your post) it's hard to say really.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, the grouping column was not defined as a factor variable. Works fine now.